# Как можно изменить сортировку подсчетом?

Tags: c++

```
void CountingSort(int *a, int *c, int n, int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        c[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c[a[i]] = c[a[i]] + 1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        while (c[j] != 0) {
            a[i] = j;
            c[j]--;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Написал данную функцию, и хочется как-то её изменить в лучшую сторону

Comment: А чем плоха текущая функция - не работает? На беглый взгляд она делает всё, что нужно.

Comment: @MBo, я хотел б ее как-то изменить без второго масива

Comment: Нет, без массива счётчиков не получится - это будет уж не сортировка подсчётом.

Comment: Не работает при отрицательных числах. Лечится дополнительным циклом для поиска минимального значения.

Comment: @AlexGlebe не могли б точнее описать как исправить?

Comment: @MBo, вас понял

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не работает при отрицательных числах. Лечится дополнительным циклом для поиска минимального значения.

поиск минимума :

```
void CountingSort(int *a, int *c, int n, int k)
{
    int min = 0 ;
    if (n)
      min = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
       if(a[i] < min)
         min = a[i]; 

...

    }
```

дальше уже работать со счётчиком, но со сдвинутым индексом.

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ++ c[a[i] - min] ;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        while (c[j] != 0) {
            a[i] = j + min;
            c[j]--;
            i++;
        }
    }
...
```

---

Если диапазон данных заранее не известен и/или данные подсчёта далее не нужны, то нужно опять посчитать этот диапазон и выделить память.

```
void CountingSort(int *a, int n)
{
  int *c ;
  int k ;
    int min = 0 ;
    int max = 0 ;
    if (n) {
      min = a[0];
      max = a[0];  }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
       if(a[i] < min)
         min = a[i];
       if(a[i] > max)
         max = a[i]; }

k = max - min + 1 ;
c = new int [ k ] ;
...
```

И не забываем потом освобождать память :

```
delete [ ] c ;
```

Comment: `void countingSort(int arr[], int n) {
    int k = n;
    int *c[k];
    int min = 0;
    if (n)
        min = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c[arr[i] - min] = c[arr[i] - min] + 1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        while (c[j] != 0) {
            arr[i] = j + min;
            c[j]--;
            i++;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: а второй масив как-то можно в функции создать?Как я питался сверху

Comment: Можно, но только в Си, в плюсах нельзя. И чисел а не указателей `int c[k];` Будут с проблемами нехватки памяти стека. Он ограничен одним мегабайтом в винде. Большими массивами можно но только в куче. `int * c = new int[k];`

Comment: ,`void countingSort(int arr[], int n) {
    int* c = new int[n];
    int min = 0;
    if (n != 0) {
        min = arr[0];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            c[arr[i] - min] = c[arr[i] - min] + 1;
        }
        i = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            while (c[j] != 0) {
                arr[i] = j + min;
                c[j]--;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: ошибка почему-то

Comment: Размер массива счётчика зависит от чисел в массиве, а не размера массива `arr`. `new int[Max - Min + 1]` Сначала ищем миним и максим. Потом создаём массив счётчик.

Comment: а проще нельзя?